# Two tables reference each other: How to insert row in an Oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables

1. `Department`
2. `Professor`

in which `Department` has an attribute called `HeadID` referencing `Professor`
and `Professor` has an attribute called `DeptID` referencing `Department`

They form a circular relationship.

But the problem is that, how to insert a row to any of these tables?

Oracle complained "parent key not found" after I tried insert a row.

Comment: if `headid` in department can be null,, first insert department, then professor, then update the department...

Comment: No. `HeadID` in `Department` and `DeptID` in `Professor` are `NOT NULL`

Comment: uh.. well you can use already existing professor for the new department and then replace them..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define one of the foreign key constraints as DEFERRABLE and defer constraint checking until the end of your transaction (instead of checking at the end of statement which ends with "parent key not found"). Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/data_int.htm#i4665)

Comment: If that design is really necessary, that deferrable constraints are the way to go (although I would probably make both constraints deferrable)

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions described here are simpler.
But if you really want the DB to describe your buisiness (which is not necessarily the best approach) then you can have another table, lets say `DEPT_HEAD_POSITIONS`. the `Department` table will have the FK (HeadID) refer to this table, and the `Professor` table will have another nullable field as a FK to this new table.

Now, what you have is:

- departments head positions
- departments (that must have a head position)
- professors (which must belong to a department and **may** be head of the department)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for a foreign key consisting of multiple columns to allow one of the columns to contain a value for which there is no matching value in the referenced columns, per the SQL-92 standard. To avoid this situation, create NOT NULL constraints on all of the foreign key's columns

[for reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html)

so I think you can insert data in one of the row without giving value in foreign key column and then insert row into second row referring value of primary key in the first table and then you can proceed ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the authority to redesign the schema you should. If not I think the simplest and best approach is described in deathApril's comment.

In the use case where you want to add a new department and a new professor who heads it, you're best of:

1. Adding the Professor under a different department
2. Adding the Department with the Professor from Step 1 as head
3. Updating the Professor record from Step 1 to refer to his new Department created in Step 2

Answer (score -1):

Oracle and SQL Server do not allow circular referencing because there is always a problem when deleting a row from a table having dependencies to another row from another table (foreign key) which refers to the row being deleted.....
For more Info: [Click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference#In_computer_programming)

Comment: Not true for Oracle. You can define the constraints as deferrable (See Marcin's answer)